# What is the font of the line number in Xcode 11?

Tags: font-identification

At first, I thought it is the same font as code (i.e., `SF Mono`).

[image]

But the comparation(left: line number, right: code) above shows that they are not.

Then I searched for fonts like `D-DIN`, which is really close.
[image]

However, it is not a monospace font. When I applied it on the website, it shows:

[image]

I guess it is a variant of D-DIN font, but anybody knows what font exactly it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same font as the code – the code is in SF Mono, these numbers are in SF Pro Text.

SF Mono contains multiple versions of designs for some digits, and it's up to the application to decide what to use where. The design for the characters `0` and `1` can be changed separately by applying a different Stylistic Set:

[image: Stylistic Set #3]

[image: Stylistic Set #4]

which as such works in all OpenType aware software such as Adobe InDesign (no version number needed, this has always been possible).

The font SF Pro has more variations, including tabular (equally spacing) versus lining (proportional) digits, and it's the latter that causes the `1`s in your screenshot appear spaced closer together.

[image: OpenType features at work]

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate font called Xcode Digits. Its TTF is located inside the Xcode.app in DVTKit.framework.

Update: actually the TTF was there in Xcode 10 and older. [image: Xcode Digits file]

Although I can't find the TTF in newer Xcode versions, the font looks the same. Here I've selected Xcode Digits as a font for numbers: [image: Xcode editor screenshot]

Xcode 4 also had a font with the same name, but it is a different font:

[image: old font]
[image: new font]

Comment: This answer contradicts what is said in the accepted answer. Could you [edit] and _elaborate_ your answer to show us why you think this is the case, maybe add a screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: This font is still available, but is now located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTUserInterfaceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Fonts